# Color change in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

how can I change in vscode color of words like "document, body, textContent etc." ?
I try change it in settings.json :

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
            "variables": "#4c8172",
    },
```

but if I change variable color, it set same color to document, body etc. I want different color of variables and this words. Check screenshot.

[my workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5zIQ.png)

I try add in settings.json specific color for variables but it doesnt work for me